# How to get current record ID?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I have a compute field and function :

When I click on res.partner list view or kanban view, the current record id's data should get calculated and display in smart button, am facing problem in getting the current ID.

```py
account_info = fields.Integer(compute='_credit_debit_info', string='# Credits and Debits')

@api.multi
def _credit_debit_info(self):
    print "...Self...",self.ids
    print "...context..",self.env.context.get('active_id')
    print "...context..", self.env.context
    for partner in self:
        if partner.with_context(active_id=True):
            PartnerInfo = self.env['account.move.line'].with_context(active_test=False).search([('partner_id', '=', partner.id),
                    ('account_id', 'in', (partner.property_account_receivable_id.id, partner.property_account_payable_id.id))])
            for acco in PartnerInfo:
                cre = sum(acco.mapped('credit'))
                debit = sum(acco.mapped('debit'))
                partner.account_info = cre - debit
```

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by current record id. in tree view and kanban view, there will be a list of records in current view

Comment: All those records will be available in self

Comment: Did you debug into the method? What happens? Is it even called?

Comment: if u r doing debug u can find antother self.active_id something like

Comment: WHy not use compute?

Comment: It is a simple way to find using self or active_id

Answer (score 2):

You could use `self.id` or `self._ids` or `self._context.get('active_id')`.

Comment: thanks, i have tried this.. iam not able to get current ID? i printed and value and tried

Comment: In the most of cases a `compute` method works in dependency to another field `@api.depends('other_field')`, take a looke the `account_invoice.py` file for the account module to get a better understanding, and please debug your method, or show what your `prints` are showing on

Comment: This works for me to take the current active_id from the URL params...